# Firebase notification token not working for Single Device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is an odd problem.

For some reason, when I try to send a notification to a single device using a Firebase token, the notification never reaches the phone (although it appears as Completed in the Firebase console); but when I try sending the notification to a user segment, the notification gets delivered successfully.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds most likely that the token is not for the device that you're using.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I'm using the token that I am getting on my iOS device using [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]

Comment: Hi. I'm presuming you're sending via the Firebase Console. Can you try sending via [Postman](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26577/sending-downstream-messages-using-postman#t=201702210220008497113) or [cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26480/sending-downstream-messages-via-curl#t=201702210220008497113) and see if it's the same scenario? Do make sure that `priority` is set to `high`.