# Firebase notification can't receive by user segment for console. but can receive using FCM registered token

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

That is my confusion.
please help me!

no problem, device can receive notification when I send to a single device using a Firebase token in firebase console.

but, device can't receive notification when I send user segment and application selection in firebase console.

my problem is perfectly opposite this question.
[Firebase notification token not working for Single Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351830/firebase-notification-token-not-working-for-single-device)

Comment: show some code to understand problem.